# How to convert any fixed width layout to flex-width layout?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to convert any fixed width layout to flexi-width layout? any quick tips?

In a website should we make every thing flexi-width, i mean left or right sidebar and main content column ?

Should we make everything in 100% width or we should define a max-width for better readability?

Answer (score 2):

Read this and you will know everything and too much. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, i would assume you have  lots of widths set to pixels.  Figure out what percentages they are relative to the screen resolution, than change the widths to percentages and tweek accordingly.
I have noticed most sites now get screen resolution, then use fixed width for main containers.